# Saber qual a checkbox clicada

Tags: android, checkbox

Tenho 20 checkboxes estáticas, ao clicar numa delas executo uma função através do `onClick`. Porém isto talvez seja uma pergunta estupida mas como é que eu sei exatamente qual das 20 checkboxes é que foi clicada? Eu para já tenho um `if` que verifica se alguma das 20 checkboxes está clicada atraves do `isChecked()==true` porém não me diz se foi checkbox a, b ou c.

eu vi esta solução

```
switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.Checkboxes_1 :
break;

case R.id.Checkboxes_2 :
break;

case R.id.Checkboxes_3 :
break;}
```

Mas então se eu tiver 20 checkboxes vou ter de fazer 20 cases?! Não há uma maneira diferente?

Comment: Depende.. para quê vc precisa saber qual foi clicada? o que vc vai fazer com essa informação? se vc acessar o this dentro da função, o this é o checkbox clicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o atributo `android:onClick` de cada CheckBox, no xml, para atribuir o método que irá tratar o *click*. Use sempre o mesmo nome paro o método.

```
android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

No java declare um método com esse nome que receba uma *View* e retorne `void`.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

}
```

A *view* passada ao método é o *CheckBox* clicado.
Faça o *cast* de *View* para *CheckBox* e use-o como quiser.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    CheckBox checkBoxClicked = (CheckBox)view;
    if(checkBoxClicked.isChecked()){

        //O CheckBox clicado foi seleccionado
        //aja de acordo
    }else{

        //O CheckBox clicado foi desseleccionado
        //aja de acordo
    }
}
```